# I need to translate multiple .mp4 video Titles at once?

Tags: python, php, google-translate, translate

Recently, I have been working on a video hosting project and we are looking to translate around 5,000 video `.mp4` files. I tried many GitHub projects, but none worked for `.mp4` files only php or JSON files.

I need to translate the files from Google translate or whatever from English to French.

For example This is the video title.mp4 to Ceci est le titre de la video.mp4

Comment: Are you talking about translating the audio ? Or the filename?

Comment: File name "Title" of the .mp4 videos

For example This is the video title.mp4 to Ceci est le titre de la video.mp4

Answer (score 1):

To get the filenames into python you can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) library to read them in so something like:

```py
from glob import glob
import os 

file_names = [os.path.basename(file) for file in glob(r`<FOLDER>\*.mp4`)] 

translated_names = translate(file_names)
```

There are so many libraries that will help you translate that I will just pass over a tutorial and you can make up your own mind which one you want to use :)

https://towardsdatascience.com/language-translation-using-python-bd8020772ccc

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I tried to go about this.
Assuming you have the `translate function` from google translate. Then get all the file names in your folder.

```
my_path = './video_files'
all_video_files = [f for f in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, f))
                    and 'mp4' in f ]
```

Then read the contents and save them in a separate folder with the translated names like:

```
for file in all_video_files:
    print(file)
    file_translated = translate(file.split('.')[0])
    with open(my_path+f'/{file}', 'rb') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        with open(f'./translated_videos/{file_translated}.mp4', 'wb') as g:
            g.write(contents)
            g.close()
        f.close()
```